# Can I unverify users in firebase programmatically?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to **unverify** users that are verified, everytime they sign out in my app. This is to achieve the behaviour I want for my app using firebase SDK. But, somehow, I can't find any solution (If it's really possible) for that. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks, BTW! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "unverify users which were verified everytime they sign out in my app"?

Comment: I mean, I want to literally unverify users programmatically. But you already answered that there is no current API for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to set the `emailVerified` property of the current user profile to `false` in the client-side SDKs for Firebase Authentication.

What you *can* do though is [modify the user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) by using the Admin SDK and set the property to `false` there.

Since the Admin SDK can only be used in trusted environments, it won't run in the client-side app, and you'll have to do this by making a custom API that your app can call. If you don't have an existing server where you can run this API, consider using a serverless solution like Cloud Functions or Cloud Run.